# Вставка разделителей в рекурсивный вывод данных

Tags: php, mysql

Есть функция:

```
function tree($id)
{
  // запрос к БД
  while (...)
    {
       echo $result['name'];
       tree($result['id']);
    }
}

tree(0);
```

Результат вывода примерно следующий:

```
Parent
->Children, Children, Children, Children
Parent
->Children, Children
Parent
->Children, Children, Children
// и так N раз
```

Какую матиматическую функцию или выражение нужно добавить, чтобы после каждого пятого добавить как бы разделитель?

Comment: я правильно понял, твоя функция выполняет сама себя из своего же цикла?

tree($result['id']);

Comment: Правильно понял!

Comment: сие творение вообще работает??

Comment: Если бы не работало, мой бы вопрос стоял примерно иначе - "Почему не работает скрипт?" Почитай инфу по типу: Использование рекурсии в PHP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function tree($id, $n)
{
    if($n && !$n%5){
        // разделитель
    }
    // запрос к БД
    while (...)
    {
        echo $result['name'];
        tree($result['id'], $n+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо 'like' то что было нужно!

Answer (score 0):

а если в while ввести счетчик . например i, и когда он равен 5 - обнулять его и писать разделитель